# Simple Registration group_id error

Tags: simple-registration

@bjornbjorn
Got Simple Registration and trying to use it for a front end member registration form, but getting the following error when trying to register via the form:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors

group_id: You must select a valid group.
```

I'm using EE 3.5.10 - the member settings should allow member registrations, and it's set to require admin moderation:
[image]
The "pending" group does exist.

Please help!

Comment: Is anyone checking these forums?
I've created a question on here and tagged it with "simple-registration" as requested on here - https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-registration-ee3 - but no response...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply :-/ If you look at Andrew's answer below it is correct, I have verified and I got the same error message you got if I locked a member group.

Comment: ok, thanks Bjorn - I'll remember that for next time a similar site comes up -
 have you already / will you be updating Simple Registration to EE4?

Answer (score 1):

This response is probably too late for you, but I've just had the same issue with the built-in EE member registration.

The solution seems to be, under Control Panel > Members > Member Groups, to unlock the groups that you are allowing members to join. Click on the member group name and click on the Security Lock switch.

Comment: Interesting.. i had thought I'd checked that too, but maybe not... have since returned the plugin, but will bear that in mind for future installs - thanks Andrew :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the group_id to the form as a select field, with the option value being the id for example...

```
 <select name="group_id" id="">
    <option value="1">Bookings</option>
    <option value="2">Members</option>
    <option value="3">Admin</option>
  </select>
```

Then it will work.

Comment: You might also choose to add it as a hidden field, so a user couldn't register themselves as 'any' user.